# Странное сообщение под ответом

Tags: поддержка, модерация

Заметил вот такую штуку:

https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/2852

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Обсуждения:
[What are these notices under my post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165006/260198)
https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/09/23/bounty-reasons-and-post-notices/

У нас ничего подобного не встречал.

Никто из модераторов этот инструмент не использует у нас? Или у нас такие сообщения не предусмотрены?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Таких уведомлений всего три - одно для вопросов, одно для ответов и одно про отсутствие ссылок на источники (которое лично мне кажется не очень подходящим для нашего сайта). Никак кастомизировать сообщение нельзя, поэтому и используются они крайне редко:

> [image: скриншот]

Comment: Можно кастомизировать через м̶а̶т̶у̶м̶б̶у̶ перевод :-D

Comment: @alexolut, но их всё равно останется 3, к тому же общих с сайтом русского языка - там как раз про ссылки может пригодиться плашка.